# Add new -- domain.sharepoint.com/subfolder/

Tags: site-collection, url, site

I am trying to create a new site collection under our SharePoint Online tenant, and can't add a new subfolder. It only allows me to create a site collection in one of the following subfolders.

https://companydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/

https://companydomain.sharepoint.com/teams/

I was hoping to create these --

https://companydomain.sharepoint.com/external/

https://companydomain.sharepoint.com/internal/

Is that possible in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in SharePoint Online.

This are called managed paths. And by default only `sites` and `teams` are available. You can't add new one.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Managed-Paths-in-SharePoint-Online/td-p/31140